# Firestore database security rules only works in simulator

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have setup firestore database and published some security rules to that database using firebase cli. But rules work only in simulator, from client side those rules are not working. Even if I prevent all read/write access to database, no changes is reflecting from client side (using firestore nodejs client library). The below rule itself will not work from client side.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

And in my nodejs code

```
  const {Firestore} = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
    const db = new Firestore();
    db.collection("users").add({
        usertype: req.body.usertype,
        email : req.body.email,
        fullname: req.body.fullname,             
        created_on : new Date()                    
    });
```

I can add new users to users collection, even if i prevent database access using rules defined above, but in simulator these rules work.
Is there any settings or pre-configuration I'm missing? Please guide me in fixing the same.

Comment: Are you using the admin SDK? Because the admin SDK bypass every rules as design. Please provide the client code you are talking about.

Comment: @MaximeGelinas No iam using @google-cloud/firestore npm library in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the server SDKs (including "@google-cloud/firestore" for node) bypass security rules.  Rules only apply when accessed from web or mobile clients (for example, Android, iOS, browser JavaScript) using the Firebase specific SDKs for those platforms.